# Javafx - set hover for barchart

Tags: javafx, hover, bar-chart

i need to set hover over the bar in barchart.

I have code which show barchart and I need to show values from y-axis when crossing over bar on graphic.

```
  XYChart.Series set1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    for(int i = 0; i< suply.size(); i++)
    {       
    set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(suply.get(i).getName(), Float.parseFloat(suply.get(i).getNum())));

      final XYChart.Data<String, Number> data  = new XYChart.Data(suply.get(i).getName(),  Float.parseFloat(suply.get(i).getNum()));

    data.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {

      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> ov, Node oldNode, Node newNode) {
        if (newNode != null) {

        }
      }
    });

    series1.getData().add(data);

    }

    barChart.getData().add(series1);

    //now you can get the nodes.
    for (Series<String, Number> serie: barChart.getData()){
        for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> item: serie.getData()){
            item.getNode().setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                System.out.println("you clicked "+item.toString()+serie.toString());
            });
        }
    }
    barChart.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
```

Where to put code for hover on barchart and how?

Comment: don't quite understand the question: if you know how/where to register a pressed handler, what's the problem with registering a tooltip?

Comment: i never work with hover, i dont now how to set, i get in console value when press barchart, but dont now how to set value on chart to see

Comment: Thanks on help, i try use tooltip

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions

```
       for (final Series<String, Number> series : barChart.getData()) {
        for (final XYChart.Data<String, Number> data : series.getData()) {
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setText(data.getXValue().toString() +" "+ 
                         data.getYValue().toString());
            Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), tooltip);
        }
    }
```